# MYSQL Select Update Distinct Column based on lowest value

Tags: join, distinct

I have the following sample table data:

```
id, price, product_id, default
905928, 2.92, 1523, 0
905929, 2.89, 1523, 0
905930, 3.92, 1524, 0
905931, 6.67, 1525, 0
905932, 11.92, 1526, 0
905933, 5.34, 1526, 0
905934, 3.92, 1527, 0
905935, 1.11, 1528, 0
```

I would like to update the default column with a 1, whenever the lowest priced item within a duplicate product id group is flagged. So the result should look like:

```
id, price, product_id, default
905928, 2.92, 1523, 0
905929, 2.89, 1523, 1
905930, 3.92, 1524, 1
905931, 6.67, 1525, 1
905932, 11.92, 1526, 0
905933, 5.34, 1526, 1
905934, 3.92, 1527, 1
905935, 1.11, 1528, 0
905936, 0.11, 1528, 1
905937, 1.89, 1528, 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update yourtable a
inner join
(select product_id, min(price) minprice from
 yourtable 
 group by product_id
) b
on a.product_id = b.product_id
inner join 
(select product_id, price, min(id) minid from
 yourtable
 group by product_id, price
) c
on a.product_id = c.product_id and c.price = b.minprice
set defaultvalue = 1
where a.price = b.minprice
and a.id = c.minid
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/823d1/1).

The second `join` is used to get the minimum value of `id` for the case where multiple records have lowest `price` for same `product_id`.

Comment: Hi shree.pat18 this is almost there. Only problem is when there are duplicate prices a 1 is placed in each column. I will need this to add a '1' to the lowest result just once, and not each duplicate time.

Comment: How do you decide which row to update? Based on the lowest `id`?

Comment: Yes, it could be based on the lowest id. But I am reasonably indifferent. As long as it flags once per product_id, and it is the lowest price.

Comment: My implementation only updates the lowest `id` for the lowest `price`, so I suppose it serves your purpose. Please remember to mark it as accepted if it helped.

Comment: Sorry i read your question before i realised the update. This solves it! Thank you.